# Selecting dates from table in database in Sqlite3, Python3

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

I'm trying to select a column from my database, which includes dates. I would like to condition the range of dates using WHERE in the c.execute() statement.

When i explicitly define the dates as follow, it works:

```
c.execute('''SELECT beacon_id, kind, value, charging_time FROM consumption WHERE charging_time > "2019-11-01" and charging_time < "2019-12-01"''')
```

But when I use begin and end dates that are entered from by the user from the keyboard as follows, it doesn't work:

```
c.execute('SELECT beacon_id, kind, value, charging_time FROM consumption WHERE charging_time > ? and charging_time < ?', t1, t2)
```

Where t1 = (beginDate,) and t2 = (endDate,).

I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: What is the format of the date parameters that you are passing? If they are not in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (or the-like), this won't work as expected.

Comment: They're YYYY-MM-DD indeed! I've tried using them as strings and as datatimes, but both ways it doesn't work!

Comment: If the dates in your table and the dates that you pass as parameters to the placeholders `?` are all in the same format: YYYY-MM-DD then your code should work.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work". Does it give an error (as written it will)?